# Checking for duplicate before inserting record into Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form where I don't want the user to be able to enter a contact with the same name.

The form has a save button. To check for a duplicate, part of that button's code is :-

```
If Me.DataEntry = False Then
Else
    'Check for duplicate contact
    If DCount("[ContactID]", "tblContactsNew", "[first_name] = " & "'" & Me.FIRST_NAME & "'" & "And [Surname] = " & "'" & Me.SURNAME & "'") <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "A contact with these details already exists:-" & vbCrLf, vbOKOnly + vbExclamation
        End
    End If
End If
```

which is before :-

```
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
```

If the count <> 0, the message is displayed. But if I then click my Cancel button, there is still a record added for the duplicate.

The code for the cancel button is :-

```
If Me.Dirty Then
Me.Undo
End If
DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
```

How can I prevent the duplicate record being written?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd migrate all that code to the forms `Form_BeforeUpdate` event.

In your save button code, the only thing you need is `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord`

Then, in your Form_BeforeUpdate event:

```
If Me.DataEntry = False Then
    Cancel = True 'Don't save the form I guess
Else
    'Check for duplicate contact
    If DCount("[ContactID]", "tblContactsNew", "[first_name] = " & "'" & Me.FIRST_NAME & "'" & "And [Surname] = " & "'" & Me.SURNAME & "'") <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "A contact with these details already exists:-" & vbCrLf, vbOKOnly + vbExclamation
        Cancel = True 'Cancel the update
        End Sub
    End If
End If
```

You can add a global to the form, set that to `True` in your cancel button, and don't save if it is `True`

Comment: This does work, in that it doesn't write the record. However (and sorry for not specifying this in the question, but the Save button is actually Save & Close. So, with the code as you suggested, the message is displayed, and then the form closes. Can I stop this from happening?

Comment: Well, you could check `Me.Dirty` before you close it (if the record got saved, it should be `True`, else `False`). But hard to say without knowing the full code

Comment: Sorry, meant that in reverse (`Me.Dirty` should be `False` if the record got saved)